# Building the portaudio golang wrapper on Windows

Tags: go, portaudio, pkg-config

I am trying to use the github.com/gordonklaus/portaudio library. This library requires portaudio to be installer. I have built a 64-bit dll of the actual C portaudio library, as the go package requires.

Running `go get github.com/gordonklaus/portaudio` results in the following output:

```
# pkg-config --cflags portaudio-2.0
Package portaudio-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `portaudio-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'portaudio-2.0' found
pkg-config: exit status 1
```

Obviously, cgo is trying to run pkg-config for the portaudio library. I need to make sure it finds it and uses it correctly. However, I do not know how to achieve this on Windows.

Comment: How did you build portaudio? What compiler did you use? Where did the library installed? I've successfully using that package in MSYS2 env. The prebuilt portaudio libary is provided.

Comment: @putu I've built portaudio via Visual Studio. The library was not installed into the system, I just have the .dll built from the sources.

Comment: I think, you need to install gcc compiler (e.g. [mingw-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/). AFAIK, Visual C++ Compiler is not supported by `cgo`. In my case, I installed [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/), `gcc` toolchain, `go`, `pkg-config` and other related *buildtools*, then install *mingw-w64-x86_64-portaudio*. See [this blog post](http://gianlucacosta.info/go-gui-apps-on-windows) for installing MSYS2.